# CPP fails sanity check on Mac

Tags: c, macos

I’ve searched everywhere and can’t find how to solve this compile problem on my Mac:

**C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check**

Update:  I'm trying to compile psqlodbc with ./configure  I get the following:

configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

Would someone be so kind as to tell me what to check to begin sorting out what could be wrong?  I have read that the problem is usually caused by multiple versions of the compiler and XCode. But, I have no idea how to even begin. Thanks!

Here is my output:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking -Wall is a valid compile option... yes
./configure: line 4392: /usr/local/iODBC: is a directory
./configure: line 4395: /usr/local/iODBC: is a directory
configure: using  
checking last argument to SQLColAttribute is SQLLEN *... no
checking for pg_config... no
checking for prove... prove
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... failed
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... no
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/Users/tedhtl/Downloads/psqlodbc-10.01.0000':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
```

Comment: In what context? What tool are you running? Got a command line you can share?

Comment: We’re going to need more information about what you’re trying to do and how you’re trying to do it. Why are you running `/lib/cpp` directly?  What message do you get when you try to run it?   Have you installed the command line tools?  (I just checked; on my Mac, it is `/usr/bin/cpp` and not `/lib/cpp` that exists.) . And `xcode-select install` may be what you need to run.

Comment: I updated my question with more info.  "Xcode-select install" doesn't work.  What are command line tools?

Comment: I just installed command line tools, but get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

go to http://developer.apple.com/xcode and click on the blue "Download" button in the upper right corner.  After you log into the website, scroll to the bottom of the page and you'll see a "See More Downloads" link.

Look for "Command Line Tools" in the list of dmg files.  It should look like this:

[image: Command Line Tools]

Get that DMG and then double click on the installer. It installs tools (like `/usr/bin/cpp`) that you can access from your command line (or Terminal.app).

Comment: Thanks!  I did that  but still get the sanity check error:  checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/Users/tedhtl/Downloads/psqlodbc-10.01.0000':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

Comment: Try quitting/restarting Terminal.app (to get a new window) and let's see if it picks up the new paths and tools.  Also, `cpp` is a tool so I'm not certain why `./configure` is looking for it in the `/lib` (libraries) directory.

Comment: Ok, I did that.  ./configure --with-unixodbc=/usr/local/iODBC still gives me the sanity check error.  I've seen other people think this is caused by variables pointed to the wrong compiler or preprocessor.  Could that be it?  I have no idea how to check that.  Many thanks!

Comment: You may want to edit your question to show what package / software you're trying to install (and the instructions you're following).  I see iODBC is a UNIX/Linux driver, so I'm honestly not certain if it exists (or builds) for macOS.

Comment: I'm not building iODBC - I already did that and it did build and install correctly.  I'm trying to install the ODBC for psql.  Others have successfully done it, but I'm stuck with the cpp error.  It has to do with my compiler environment, I'm sure.

Comment: I edited my question with the ./configure output.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. I had the same question while compiling the odb lib for odb sqlite.
2. After looking at the answer from @Michael Dautermann, I ran the command "/usr/bin/cpp -v" to get the include path

```
#include <...> // search starts here:
/usr/local/include
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
```

3. Updated the CPPFLAGS with include info from the above command.
4. It worked after re-configuring, as shown below, with the updated CPPFLAGS

`/configure --disable-threads --disable-static CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-5 CPPFLAGS=-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/5 CFLAGS=-O3 CXXFLAGS=-O3`
I hope this will help you or others

Comment: mac osx 10.14 majove  g++5.0 lib-odb